# What files need to stay on the device for a clockworkmod?

Tags: sd-card, clockworkmod-recovery

I installed a *clockworkmod* months ago to an Alcatel OneTouch 995. On the SDCard there is still a `clockworkmod` folder. The directory structure looks like follows:

```
└── clockworkmod
    └── backup
        └── OT995_4.0.4-FR
            ├── boot.img
            ├── custpack.ext4.tar
            ├── nandroid.md5
            └── system.ext4.tar
```

I wonder if the folder needs to stay on the card. Can you please explain why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clockworkmod` folder contains data that CWM created, and more specifically the `backup` folder is where your device's backup files are stored. All of those files are what constitute a Nandroid backup of your device.

If you're looking to free up some space on your device you *can* delete the folder, but CWM will recreate only the folder every time you reboot; the backup files will *not* be recreated, and will only be generated when you use the **Backup** feature so be sure to copy these files to a computer (for backup purposes should you ever need to restore it).

I often create Nandroid backups, copy them to a computer or external storage, and then delete them from my device to save the memory for more useful things.

Comment: Are those files a backup of the currently running Android version or of the system which was installed before?

Comment: @JJD They are as recent as from when you last created the backup while in Recovery mode. CWM does not make backups automatically. I would look at the file metadata to know when they were created and that might indicate to you which ROM they correspond to. If you don't recall when you used the Backup feature, then chances are you did it as part of a tutorial or while experimenting with it. Either way, its always a good idea to have a backup (or several, at that). :)